# What is wrong with this line of code?

Tags: bash, scripting, echo, graphviz

I've got this code I can't seem to get running:

```
 echo "digraph G{"; cat "$file"; echo "}" | dot -T png > graph.png
```

The terminal echoes all it should but gets stuck on the } symbol. I guess there's something wrong syntactically.

```
 Warning: <stdin>: syntax error in line 1 near '}'
```

Could you please be of quick help?

Comment: Do you want all the content from `diagraph CG{` up to `}` to be executed by `dot`? If so, now you are just passing the last `echo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you meant to send all the output of the various statements to `dot`, like this:

```
{
  echo "digraph CG{"
  cat "$tmp"
  echo "}"
} | dot -T png > callgraph.png
```

Comment: Or `echo "digraph CG{$(<$tmp)}" | dot -T png > callgraph.png`.

Answer (score 3):

With bash, you can collapse the echo;cat;echo

```
echo "digraph CG{$(< "$tmp")}" | dot ...
```

Or, if you like the extra newlines

```
printf 'digraph CG{\n%s\n}\n' "$(< "$tmp")" | dot ...
```